# How to detect integer values from the Image in android using image processing?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, integer

hai i need to find the integer values from the image using image processing i go through some image processing alogorith like edge dectection but did not get a solution can any one show some example of dectecting the integer values from a image ?

Answer (score 1):

Well for image recognition and stuff like that in general we use [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network). Implementing a basic neural network is not hard, but there are countless implementations out there in the wild (native C/C++ and Java as well).

How ever I would strongly recommend to use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library which is somehow complex but would allow you to do far more advance things.

Note: there is a port for Android and you can find it here: [OpenCV 4 Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android)

Comment: hey i got a edge dection but i have a proble it shows only preview i need to take the snap of that image how?